# Caffe compilation fails due to unsupported gcc compiler version

Tags: gcc, cuda, g++, caffe, nvcc

I struggle with [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) compilation. Unfortunately I failed to compile it.

[Steps](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#cmake-compilation) I followed:

```
git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
cd caffe
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make all
```

Running `make all` fails with the following error message:

```
[  2%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/cuda_compile_generated_im2col.cu.o
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:59:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/include/host_config.h:82:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc 4.9 and up are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc 4.9 and up are not supported!
  ^
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_im2col.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating /mydir/caffe/build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/./cuda_compile_generated_im2col.cu.o
```

Software version:

- OS: `Debian`.
- `gcc` version: `5.3.1`.
- `nvcc` version: `6.5.12`.
- `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version` result:

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  352.63  Sat Nov  7 21:25:42 PST 2015
GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.5 (Debian 4.8.5-3)
```

---

### Attempts to solve the problem

#### *1st try*

Simple solutions are often best ones, so (as suggested [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/516939/cuda4-1-gcc-4-6/)) I tried to comment out macro checking `gcc` version from `/usr/include/host_config.h` (line 82). Unfortunately it doesn't work and compilation fails badly:

```
1 catastrophic error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000069c2_00000000-4_im2col.cpp4.ii".
```

#### *2nd try*

I tried to run:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.8 ..
make
```

but it fails with *exactly* the same error message (even though `g++-4.8` should be accepted).

#### *3rd try*

I've found [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009785/cuda-6-5-complains-about-not-supporting-gcc-4-9-what-to-do) (though not related to *Caffe*) and I tried to solve it as suggested in the accepted answer.

What I did:

1. I've ran `grep -iR "find_package(CUDA" caffe` command and found [`Cuda.cmake`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/cmake/Cuda.cmake) file which has `find_package(CUDA 5.5 QUIET)` in line [225](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/cmake/Cuda.cmake#L225).
2. I added `set(CUDA_HOST_COMPILER /usr/bin/gcc-4.8)` to [`Cuda.cmake`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/cmake/Cuda.cmake), line before line: `find_package(CUDA 5.5 QUIET)`.
3. I removed everything from `build` directory and ran `cmake` and `make` again - with and without `-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.8`.

Unfortunately result is exactly the same. Caffe probably overwrites it somehow - I didn't figure it out *how*.

`make VERBOSE=1 2>&1 | grep -i compiler-bindir` returns nothing.

What's interesting, `make VERBOSE=1` prints command that fails, which is:

```
/usr/bin/nvcc -M -D__CUDACC__ /mydir/caffe/src/caffe/util/im2col.cu -o /mydir/caffe/build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/cuda_compile_generated_im2col.cu.o.NVCC-depend -ccbin /usr/bin/cc -m64 -DUSE_LMDB -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_OPENCV -DWITH_PYTHON_LAYER -DGTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE -Xcompiler ,\"-fPIC\",\"-Wall\",\"-Wno-sign-compare\",\"-Wno-uninitialized\",\"-O3\",\"-DNDEBUG\" -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=cc_clobber_ignored -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=integer_sign_change -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=useless_using_declaration -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=set_but_not_used -Xcompiler -fPIC -DNVCC -I/usr/include -I/mydir/caffe/src -I/usr/include -I/mydir/caffe/build/include -I/usr/include/hdf5/serial -I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include/atlas -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/mydir/caffe/include -I/mydir/caffe/build
```

when I add `--compiler-bindir /usr/bin/gcc-4.8` flag manually, it prints error:

```
nvcc fatal   : redefinition of argument 'compiler-bindir'
```

which may be related to [this](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13674) bug report.

**Edit:** I didn't notice that `--compiler-bindir` and `-ccbin` are the same options, and the latter is already set in above command that failed. When I changed `-ccbin /usr/bin/cc` to `-ccbin /usr/bin/gcc-4.8` in above command that failed, it completes successfully. Now I need to find option in Caffe's CMake file that overwrite `-ccbin` in all subsequent Caffe's CMakes. Looking at `cmake/Cuda.cmake:252:list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${NVCC_FLAGS_EXTRA}` seems to be good way to go.

---

How can I successfully complete my compilation? Any help is appreciated.

Related SO questions:

- [*host_config.h:unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 4.9 are not supported*.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886654/host-config-hunsupported-gnu-version-gcc-versions-later-than-4-9-are-not-suppo)
- [*CUDA 6.5 complains about not supporting gcc 4.9 - what to do?*.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009785/cuda-6-5-complains-about-not-supporting-gcc-4-9-what-to-do)

Comment: you seem to mix gcc compiler and nvcc compiler (GPU code compiler). Please try and pinpoint the issue: is it with compiling CPU code or GPU? what happens if you define in Makefile.config `CPU_ONLY := 1`? are you able to build CPU only version of caffe?

Comment: If you want to use CUDA 6.5, start with [a OS/Distro that is officially supported by CUDA 6.5](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/docs/CUDA_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf) (<-click and read the documentation, especially section 1.1 and table 1) and don't make any updates to gnu/gcc/g++.

Comment: @Shai In the above post I pasted `/usr/bin/nvcc -M -D__CUDACC__ (...)` command which causes error message. This line clearly states that the problem concerns GPU compilation ran by *Caffe*'s compilation process. AFAIK `nvcc` internally uses `gcc` on Linux. See `nvcc --help` to see  `--compiler-bindir` (`-ccbin`) parameter description.

Comment: @RobertCrovella No Debian in [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/docs/CUDA_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf). Shame. ;(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cmake -D CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-ccbin gcc-4.8" .. && make` causes **successful compilation**.

---

Now another problem showed up: linking Google's `libgflags` or `libprotobuf` fails probably due to fact that it was compiled with newer `gcc` version but it's not related to asked question.

Answer (score 1):

My machine runs Ubuntu 15.10, and my default compiler version is gcc 5.2.1 .

Commenting out the #error directive in line 115 of file

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include/host_config.h
```

(or whatever the path on your system is) did the trick for me. Caffe compiled fine, all tests ran smoothly.

On the other hand, if one chooses to ignore this and proceed to compile part of the project with one compiler version, part of the project with another (for me it was gcc-4.8 and gcc-5.2.1), linking problems will arise. The linking problems of protobuf and libgflags another answer mentions are *not* unrelated to this.